# Not updating modal body

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an empty modal on my page and I'm performing an ajax call as below (simplified for reading)

```
function returnIt(x)
{
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"link",
    data:{id:"123"},
    success: function(data)
        {
        data=JSON.parse(data);
        var content=document.getElementById("returnItModalBody").innerHTML;
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
            if(data[i]["nick"]==1)
               content+="<p>"+data[i]["upd"]+"</p>";
            else
               content+="<p>"+data[i]["upd"]+"</p>";
            }
        alert(content);
        $("#returnItModal").modal('show');
        }
     });
}
```

When I tell the script to alert with `content` it shows it should show in modal.
When modal opens, there is nothing in its body.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: "simplified for reading" — It's pretty hard to read, and has obvious syntax errors in it. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript and JQuery both? The issue is that you don't assign the content back to the modal body. You need to assign it back to modal body

Comment: How does your model know what content to show ? Don't you have to explicitly pass that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var content=document.getElementById("returnItModalBody").innerHTML;
> ```

That copies the value of `innerHTML` (a string) to `content`.

> ```
> content+="<p>"+data[i]["upd"]+"</p>";
> ```

Then you assign a new string to `content`

> ```
> alert(content)
> ```

Then you look at the string in `content`

---

You never change `innerHTML`.

If you want to change `innerHTML` then you have to assign a new value to it.